# Calling shapefiles as inputs and creating a list

Tags: python, shapefile, list

I am working on writing my first script (Im a noob) to automate a task where we combine data from a hydrology dataset stored in a database and clip it to the project area boundary which is a shapefile.

1. Can I call out the location of each dataset as a variable?
2. Can I use the 'for fc in *variable*' to populate my list?

I have the code below and the comments hopefully make clear what I am trying to do. Im just a bit stuck!

```py
#IMPORTING MODULES
import arcpy

#SETTING DATA LOCATIONS

#location of the project boundary
ProjBndry = r"C:\TT_Jobs\GIS_Testing\Data\Shapefiles\Project_Boundary\ROW_Buffer1.shp"

#location of the hydrology data database
HydroData = r"C:\TT_Jobs\GIS_Testing\Data\HydrologyData\Illinois\NHDH_IL.gdb"
arcpy.env.workspace = HydroData

#set overwrite to true
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

#setting up the scratch workspace to be in the temp folder -> C:\Users\username\Documents\ArcGIS\
tempData = arcpy.CreateScratchName(workspace=arcpy.env.scratchGDB)

#Create a new list
HydroList = []


#list all of the feature classes in the NHD database
HydroList = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()

Line = "NHDFlowline"
Area = "NHDArea"
Body = "NHDWaterbody"

#Select all datasets containing the partial name of NHDLine NHDArea NHDWaterbody from the user defined NHD database 
#For each feature class in HydroData that contains List Area or Body add it to HydroList
for fc in HydroData:
    #Check for Line
    if Line in fc:
    #add it to the list
     HydroList.append(fc)
    
    #Check for Area
    if Area in fc:
    #add it to the list
     HydroList.append(fc)
    
    #Check for Body
    if Body in fc:
    #add it to the list
     HydroList.append(fc)
print HydroList


#Select all of the feature classes containing partial keywords that contain our data

#possibly Create a 1 mile buffer of project boundary

#Select all feature classes that fall within the boundary or buffer

#Create new files and join together. export them to the proper workspace

#Clip the final files to the extent of the project or buffered area
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there are a couple of problems here:

1. You create HydroList as an empty list and then on the next line replace it with a list of feature classes in your workspace (your GDB).
2. Your for loop calls HydroData to loop through, but because HydroData is a string it will not iterate through the feature classes like you want it to.

I would alter the code to look like this:

```
#IMPORTING MODULES
import arcpy

#SETTING DATA LOCATIONS

#location of the project boundary
ProjBndry = r"C:\TT_Jobs\GIS_Testing\Data\Shapefiles\Project_Boundary\ROW_Buffer1.shp"

#location of the hydrology data database
HydroData = r"C:\TT_Jobs\GIS_Testing\Data\HydrologyData\Illinois\NHDH_IL.gdb"
arcpy.env.workspace = HydroData

#set overwrite to true
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

#setting up the scratch workspace to be in the temp folder -> C:\Users\username\Documents\ArcGIS\
tempData = arcpy.CreateScratchName(workspace=arcpy.env.scratchGDB)


#list all of the feature classes in the NHD database
FC_List = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()

#Create a new list to store the desired feature class names
HydroList = []


Line = "NHDFlowline"
Area = "NHDArea"
Body = "NHDWaterbody"

#Select all datasets containing the partial name of NHDLine NHDArea NHDWaterbody from the user defined NHD database 
#For each feature class in HydroData that contains List Area or Body add it to HydroList
for fc in FC_List:
    #Check for Line
    if Line in fc:
    #add it to the list
     HydroList.append(fc)
    
    #Check for Area
    if Area in fc:
    #add it to the list
     HydroList.append(fc)
    
    #Check for Body
    if Body in fc:
    #add it to the list
     HydroList.append(fc)
print HydroList


#Select all of the feature classes containing partial keywords that contain our data

#possibly Create a 1 mile buffer of project boundary

#Select all feature classes that fall within the boundary or buffer

#Create new files and join together. export them to the proper workspace

#Clip the final files to the extent of the project or buffered area
```